# preg_match help, simple for most

Tags: preg-match

I'm trying to match all the URLs that end in .html and if they have ? after it's OK but if it's odd then not so

preg_match("/article-(.+?).html/i", getenv('REQUEST_URI'))  <-- good
preg_match("/article-(.+?).html**?**/i", getenv('REQUEST_URI'))  <-- good

basically i want to match it if it end in .html or ends in .html? and if it has a ? then anything after is ok.  So basically

article-1.html <-- "true"

article-1.html? <-- "true"

article-1.html?sdfasdfas  <-- "true"

article-1.html%20blah <-- "false"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This passed my testing:

```
preg_match("/article-(.+?).html(?![^?\"'])/i", getenv('REQUEST_URI'))
```